# How to set image shape in Python for Tensorflow prediction?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm dealing with the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (32, 32, 3) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 32, 32, 3)'
```

The placeholder is set to: `x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 32, 32, 3))`

And the image (when running `print(img1.shape)`) has the output: `(32, 32, 3)`

How can I update the image to be aligned when running: `print(sess.run(correct_prediction, feed_dict={x: img1}))`

Comment: reshape img to (1, 32, 32, 3)

Comment: Thanks! Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: img.reshape((1, 32, 32, 3))

Comment: Thanks that is it!

Answer (score 1):

The placeholder `x` in your program represents a **batch** of 32x32 (presumably) RGB images, for which predictions will be computed in a single step. If you want to compute a prediction on a single image—i.e. an array of shape `(32, 32, 3)`—you must reshape it to have an additional leading dimension. There are many ways to do this, but [`np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) is one nice way to do it:

```
 img1 = ...                             # Array of shape (32, 32, 3)
 img1_as_batch = img1[np.newaxis, ...]  # Array of shape (1, 32, 32, 3)

 print(sess.run(correct_prediction, feed_dict={x: img1_as_batch}))
```